# def array = response.data[?(@.name=='#(name)')] is not working in karatae

Tags: karate

API is
{ data: [{ name: 'John', age: 30 }, { name: 'Rahul', age: 38 }, { name: 'Arun', age:42 }] }

- def name = 'Arun'
- def array = response.data[?(@.name=='#(name)')][0]
  is not working
  cannot use Arun directly as it is taken from another service as saved in name variable .

tried using karatae 1.2  for finding array with the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
Feature: Test Feature
 Scenario: Test Scenario
    * def response =
      """
      { "data": 
      [
      { "name": "John", "age": 30 }, 
      { "name": "Rahul", "age": 38 }, 
      { "name": 'Arun', "age":42 }
      ] 
      }
      """
    * match response.data[*] contains [{ "name": "John", "age": 30 }, { "name": "Rahul", "age": 38 }, { "name": 'Arun', "age":42 }]
```

Comment: cannot use arun  need to use the variable in which the name is saved as name will change from arun to rahul or some other name

Comment: Some other name? I did not get your use case. Anyway, I have updated my answer. Just wait for other's answer.

Comment: i need to find the age of a person with the name which is taken from another api and saved in a variable it can be arun,rahul or any think

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `JsonPath` filter when your variable is dynamic: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#jsonpath-filters.

Example from the Karate readme:

```
* def temp = karate.jsonPath(cat, "$.kittens[?(@.name=='" + bob.name + "')]")
```